# Accessing elements of a kinetic group

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to construct the equivalent of a Button object using Kinetic and have run into an issue.

I am grouping a Rect and a Text object to form the button. I want to modify the properties of each of these objects after the Button has been created. Here is what I have so far.

The problem is that I want to change the text, the Rect color and stroke, and position, but is not apparent to me how to access the nodes within the group to do this.

Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/oviron/Y4XXC/

```
<button id="more">Add a new Line</button>
<button id="col">color</button>
<button id="rng">ring</button>
<button id="nam">name</button>
<div id="container"></div>

var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 350,
    height: 350
});

var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

var r1 = addRect(10, 10, 35, 35, "red", 99);

function addRect(x, y, w, h, c, txt){
    var grp = new Kinetic.Group();
    var rectangle = new Kinetic.Rect({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        width: w,
        height: h,
        fill: c,
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 2
    });

    var rectangleText = new Kinetic.Text({
        x: x + 5,
        y: y + 5,
        text: txt,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontFamily: 'Calibri',
        fill: 'white',
        align: 'center'
    });

    grp.add(rectangle);
    grp.add(rectangleText);
    layer.add(grp);
    layer.draw();
    return grp;
}

$("#more").click(function(){
    var x1=Math.random()*200+10;
    var y1=Math.random()*200+10;
    r1.setX(x1);
    r1.setY(y1);
    layer.draw();   
});

$("#col").click(function(){
    r1.setFill("green");
    layer.draw();    
});

$("#rng").click(function(){
    r1.setStroke("red");
    layer.draw();    
});

$("#nam").click(function(){
    //var shape = r1.find('#rectangleText')[0];
    this.get('.rectangleText').setText(prompt('66'));
    //children.setText("TEST");
    //shape.setText(Math.random()*100);
    //shape.getLayer().draw();
    layer.draw();    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your r1 is a reference to the group.

You need to change the color of the rect inside the group, so you need a reference to the Rect itself.

To change the color of the rect inside the group:

```
var rect=r1.find("Rect")[0];
rect.setFill("green");
layer.draw();
```

Same with the Text inside the group.

```
var text=r1.find("Text")[0];
text.setText("anything new");
layer.draw();
```

Comment: I see now. Well I was close when I tried     shape = r1.find('#rectangleText')[0];  I thought the parameter for the "find" call was to reference the node in the group but it references the type in the group. So does that mean that the index of [0] relates to if there is more than one of that type within the group?

Comment: Exactly, .find will return a set of kinetic objects so [0] gets the first from the set.  If you need a more refined .find you can set the "id:myShape'" property on myShape and get it directly with .find("#myShape")[0].